# Flood filling for number plate recognition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, flood-fill, mathematical-morphology

I have a number plate which is a binary image.

[image]

I performed dilation to the image to thicken the edges then "flood filling", lastly erosion for thinning:

[image]

But i want my output to be like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me, please? And show me how to get the desired output.

```
ab=imread('test1.png');

level=graythresh(ab);
ab=im2bw(ab,level);

se=strel('disk',1);
ab=imdilate(ab,se); 


ab=imfill(ab,'holes');
ab=bwmorph(ab,'thin',1);
ab=imerode(ab,strel('line',3,90));

figure();imshow(ab,[]); title('floodFilling');
```

Comment: Posting (the relevant part of) your code may help you get a good answer

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a few other clever calls to `imfill`. Here is a way, assuming your binary image is in the array `BW`:

```
Tmp = imfill(BW, 'holes');
Tmp2 = imfill(Tmp-BW, 'holes');
Res = Tmp - imfill(BW & Tmp2, 'holes');
```

and `Res` is a binary image that contains the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Text is just single layer fill so I do it in **C++** like this:

```cpp
int x,y,e;
int c0=0x00000000; // space color
int c1=0x00FFFFFF; // edge color
int co=0x00FF0000; // outside tmp color
int ci=0x000000FF; // inside tmp color
// grow/flood fill c0 neigbouring c1 with c2
#define fill(c0,c1,c2)\
for (e=1;e;)\
 for (e=0,y=1;y<pic1.ys-1;y++)\
  for (   x=1;x<pic1.xs-1;x++)\
   if (pic1.p[y][x].dd==c0)\
    if ((pic1.p[y-1][x].dd==c1)\
      ||(pic1.p[y+1][x].dd==c1)\
      ||(pic1.p[y][x-1].dd==c1)\
      ||(pic1.p[y][x+1].dd==c1)) { e=1; pic1.p[y][x].dd=c2; }
// copy data pic0 is source pic1 is output
pic1=pic0;
// 0. draw border rectangle for growth fill start with co
for (x=0        ,y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++) pic1.p[y][x].dd=co;
for (x=pic1.xs-1,y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++) pic1.p[y][x].dd=co;
for (x=0,y=0        ;x<pic1.xs;x++) pic1.p[y][x].dd=co;
for (x=0,y=pic1.ys-1;x<pic1.xs;x++) pic1.p[y][x].dd=co;
fill(c0,co,co); // 1. grow outer border
fill(c1,co,co); // 2. grow outer edges
fill(c0,co,ci); // 3. create outer fill edge
fill(c0,ci,ci); // 4. fill the inside
// 5. merge / recolor
for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++)
 for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;x++)
    {
    e=c0;
    if ((pic0.p[y][x].dd==c1)||(pic1.p[y][x].dd==ci)) e=c1;
    pic1.p[y][x].dd=e;
    }
#undef fill
```

Here are how the stages looks like:

- [image: stages]

Algorithm is like this:

1. draw border rectangle for growth fill start with `co` (some unused color)
2. grow outer border to nearest text edges with `co`
3. fill outer edges (they disappear) with `co`
4. create outer fill edge with `ci` (some unused color)
5. fill the inside with `ci`
6. merge / recolor source and result images

   copy edges from source image and inside from result image the rest is space

I use my own picture class for images so some members are:

`xs,ys` size of image in pixels

 `p[y][x].dd` is pixel at (x,y) position as 32 bit integer type

 `clear(color)` - clears entire image

 `resize(xs,ys)` - resizes image to new resolution

If you have special characters that have more layers

then just add more stages ... `layer` is how many layers of space there can be from most inner space/hole to the outer space also you can loop until no more layer found ...

Answer (score -1):

let use this code it will use for you . thanks to  @ spektre .

```
 ab=imread('test1.png');

level=graythresh(ab);
ab=im2bw(ab,level);

se=strel('disk',1);
ab=imdilate(ab,se);
figure();imshow(ab,[]); title('floodFilling');
ab1=imfill(ab,'holes');
ab1(ab==1)=0;
figure();imshow(ab1,[]); title('floodFilling');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, the output is completely different from what the OP asked.