# Render filled complex polygons with large number of vertices with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, triangulation, concave

I use OpenGL to render 2D map and in the process I need to render filled polygons with large number of vertices(`100,000+`). To do this, I tessellated the polygons to triangles using glu tessellator and  rendered the triangles with VBO.

The polygons are rendered successfully. **The problem is that the tessellation process turns out to be extremely slow.** For some charts with `500,000` vertices, it will take nearly **2 mins** on my laptop(i5-3230M 2.6GHz, 8G RAM). This is unacceptable for my application.

Are there any other tessellation algorithm faster than glu tessellator?

Or I have done it wrong?

The following two images are the the rendering results with

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE)
```

[image: polygons with wireframe turned on]
[image: closer look]

**EDIT :**  The map data is static and the original polygon data is in latitude-longitude format. I've already saved the tessellated polygon data (those triangles) in separate file.

To be more clear(Not directly related to the issue),for rendering on screen, a projection is needed to transform the LL format to screen coordinates.

The problem is that the user may have thousands of charts to install(in which the tessellation will be done). Although the tessellation will be run only once, it still takes too long.

Answer (score 2):

is the map static or dynamic?

**For static maps**

why not store tesselated polygons in some file and not tesselate it again ...

**For dynamic maps**

would be may be faster using different rendering approach that do not need tesselation to convex polygons like this:

1. **clear screen with island color**
2. **render islands outlines**

   not filled primitives like `GL_LINE_LOOP` do not need to tesselate at all.
3. **fill in the watter**

   simply start from point outside any polygon and flood fill the map with watter. If the flood fill is coded right (no recursion and fill with lines instead of pixels) then it should take just few [ms]. The problem with this approach is that you need to access the rendered stuff so you need at least 2 passes of rendering. Also implementing flood filling on **GPU** is not easy.

   There are also alternatives like storing edge points on **CPU** side and pre-compute the watter filling on **CPU** side. In that case you need to have list of `x` coordinates for every `y` scan line of image that will hold the start and end points for each land. then just fill in the gaps in single render pass...

   This should be rendered in **RT** easily

**[Edit] Grow Fill test Demo**

Did some testing with iterative grow filling on your data. There are some problems with the dataset like your polygons overlap which is possibly just holes but as I do not have filling color info but just object **ID** instead so it is hard to say. Anyway that can be repaired too. Here small win 32 **VCL/OpenGL/SW** demo with approach I mentioned above (**Dynamic maps**):

- [Win32 Demo](https://ulozto.net/!MllcUueEqsnm/gl-hugemap-growfill-zip) use Slow download which is free and no need for any registration just input the code.

It is Win32 stand alone no install using OpenGL+VCL

- mouse wheel zooms
- Shift+mouse wheel selects different polygon
- mouse+Left button pans

There are few issues which can be repaired but as proof of concept it works well. I compiled your ASCII map into binary form (so it loads faster but the form is the same just count of polygons, then count of points per polygon and the points x,y as 64 bit doubles. Counts are 32bit ints)

I am using my own OpenGL engine (which I can not share) so you would need to encode the stuff (like OpenGL,[FBO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43930271/2521214) and Texture init/set/usage). Anyway here the **C++** code for this **VCL** app:

```
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
#include "gl/OpenGL3D_double.cpp"
#include "performance.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
// VCL
TMain *Main;
// OpenGL
OpenGLtime tim;
OpenGLscreen scr;
OpenGL_FBO fbo;
GLuint txr_map=-1;
// miscel
int pn=0;                       // vertex count
double px0,px1,py0,py1;         // bbox
double mx,my;                   // mouse
double view[16],iview[16];      // direct and inverse Modelview matrix
double zoom=1.0,dzoom=1.1,viewx=0.0,viewy=0.0;  // view
int index=0;                    // selected polygon
bool _redraw=true;
DWORD cl_water=0xFFEE9040;
DWORD cl_land =0xFF70A0B0;
DWORD cl_edge =0xFF000000;
DWORD cl_sel  =0xFF00FFFF;
AnsiString tcpu,tgpu;
// map
List< List<double> > polygon;   // loaded polygons
      List<double>   water;     // points with water from last frame
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void view_compute()
    {
    double x,y;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    x=divide(1.0,px1-px0)*scr.aspect;
    y=divide(1.0,py1-py0)*scr._aspect;
    if (x>y) x=y;
    x*=zoom;
    glTranslated(viewx,viewy,0.0);
    glScaled(x,x,1.0);
    glTranslated(-0.5*(px0+px1),-0.5*(py0+py1),0.0);
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,view);
    glPopMatrix();
    matrix_inv(iview,view);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_load_csv(AnsiString filename)
    {
    BYTE *dat;
    AnsiString lin,s,s0;
    int ix,i,l,hnd,siz,adr;
    double x,y;
    List< AnsiString > id;

         id.allocate(128);      id.num=0;
    polygon.allocate(128); polygon.num=0;

    hnd=FileOpen(filename,fmOpenRead); if (hnd<0) return;
    siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);
        FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    dat=new BYTE[siz]; if (dat==NULL) { FileClose(hnd); return; }
    siz=FileRead(hnd,dat,siz);
    FileClose(hnd);

    adr=0; txt_load_lin(dat,siz,adr,true);
    for (ix=-1,s0="";adr<siz;)
        {
        lin=txt_load_lin(dat,siz,adr,true);
        if (lin=="") continue;
        i=1; l=lin.Length();
        s=str_load_str(lin,i,true); s=s.SubString(2,s.Length()-2);
        if (s0!=s)
            {
            for (ix=0;ix<id.num;ix++) if (id[ix]==s) break;
            if (ix>=id.num)
                {
                ix=id.num;
                id.add(s);
                polygon.add();
                polygon[ix].allocate(256);
                polygon[ix].num=0;
                }
            s0=s;
            }
        s=str_load_str(lin,i,true); s=s.SubString(2,s.Length()-2); x=str2flt(s);
        s=str_load_str(lin,i,true); s=s.SubString(2,s.Length()-2); y=str2flt(s);
        polygon[ix].add(x);
        polygon[ix].add(y);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_save_bin(AnsiString filename)
    {
    int hnd,i;
    hnd=FileCreate(filename); if (hnd<0) return;
    FileWrite(hnd,&polygon.num,4);
    for (i=0;i<polygon.num;i++)
        {
        FileWrite(hnd,&polygon[i].num,4);
        FileWrite(hnd,polygon[i].dat,polygon[i].num*8);
        }
    FileClose(hnd);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_load_bin(AnsiString filename)
    {
    int hnd,i,n,m;
    hnd=FileOpen(filename,fmOpenRead); if (hnd<0) return;
    FileRead(hnd,&n,4);
    polygon.allocate(n); polygon.num=n;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        FileRead(hnd,&m,4);
        polygon[i].allocate(m); polygon[i].num=m;
        FileRead(hnd,polygon[i].dat,m*8);
        }
    FileClose(hnd);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_bbox()
    {
    int ix,i,n;
    double *p,a;
    pn=0;
    px0=px1=polygon[0][0];
    py0=py1=polygon[0][1];
    for (ix=0;ix<polygon.num;ix++)
        {
        p=polygon[ix].dat;
        n=polygon[ix].num; pn+=n>>1;
        for (i=0;i<n;i+=2)
            {
            a=*p; p++; if (px0>a) px0=a; if (px1<a) px1=a;
            a=*p; p++; if (py0>a) py0=a; if (py1<a) py1=a;
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_draw()
    {
    int ix,i,n;
    double *p,a;
//  glLineWidth(2.0);
    for (ix=0;ix<polygon.num;ix++)
        {
        p=polygon[ix].dat;
        n=polygon[ix].num;
        if (ix==index) glColor4ubv((BYTE*)&cl_sel);
         else          glColor4ubv((BYTE*)&cl_edge);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for (i=0;i<n;i+=2,p+=2) glVertex2dv(p);
        glEnd();
        }
//  glLineWidth(1.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    tbeg();
    tim.tbeg();

    // [ render outline to texture ]
    fbo.bind(scr);
    glClearColor(divide((cl_land)&255,255),divide((cl_land>>8)&255,255),divide((cl_land>>16)&255,255),1.0);
    scr.cls();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixd(view);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (water.num)  // water start points for grow fill
        {
        // add water around txr border
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)&cl_water);
        for (int i=0;i<water.num;i+=2)
         glVertex2dv(water.dat+i);
        glEnd();
        }

    map_draw();
    scr.exe();

    fbo.unbind(scr);

    // [ copy GL texture to CPU image ]
    scr.txrs.txr_ld(txr_map);
    // [ create ScanLines for direct pixel access pyx[y][x] ]
    int e,x,y,xs,ys; DWORD **pyx,*p,c0,c1; double a[3];
    xs=scr.txrs.txr.xs;                     // texture resolution (rounded up to power of 2)
    ys=scr.txrs.txr.ys;
    pyx=new DWORD*[ys];
    p=(DWORD*)scr.txrs.txr.txr;             // CPU image pixel data
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++,p+=xs) pyx[y]=p;      // scan line pointers

    // [ Grow Fill water ]
    c0=rgb2bgr(cl_land);
    c1=rgb2bgr(cl_water);
    if (water.num==0)   // first frame view must be set so water is on all borders
        {
        // add water around txr border
        for (x=   1,y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y][x]=c1;
        for (x=xs-2,y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y][x]=c1;
        for (y=   1,x=0;x<xs;x++) pyx[y][x]=c1;
        for (y=ys-2,x=0;x<xs;x++) pyx[y][x]=c1;
        }

    for (e=1;e;)                            // grow it
    for (e=0,y=1;y<ys-1;y++)
     for (   x=1;x<xs-1;x++)
      if (pyx[y][x]==c0)
       if ((pyx[y-1][x]==c1)
         ||(pyx[y+1][x]==c1)
         ||(pyx[y][x-1]==c1)
         ||(pyx[y][x+1]==c1)) { e=1; pyx[y][x]=c1; }

    // create water start points for next frame
    water.num=0;
    e=4;    // step
    for (y=1;y<ys-2;y+=e)
     for (x=1;x<xs-2;x+=e)
       if ((pyx[y-1][x-1]==c1) // enough water around (x,y)?
         &&(pyx[y-1][x  ]==c1)
         &&(pyx[y-1][x+1]==c1)
         &&(pyx[y  ][x-1]==c1)
         &&(pyx[y  ][x  ]==c1)
         &&(pyx[y  ][x+1]==c1)
         &&(pyx[y+1][x-1]==c1)
         &&(pyx[y+1][x  ]==c1)
         &&(pyx[y+1][x+1]==c1))
            {
            // convert pixel(x,y) -> World(x,y)
            a[0]=divide(2.0*x,xs)-1.0;
            a[1]=divide(2.0*y,ys)-1.0;
            a[2]=0.0;
            matrix_mul_vector(a,iview,a);
            water.add(a[0]);
            water.add(a[1]);
            }

    // [ copy CPU image back to GL texture ]
    delete[] pyx;                           // release ScanLines no need for them anymore
    scr.txrs.txr.rgb2bgr();                 // I got RGB/BGR mismatch somewhere
    scr.txrs.txr_st(txr_map);               // scr.txrs.txr.txr holds pointer to 32bit pixel data
    scr.exe();

    // [ render texture to screen ]
    scr.cls();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    scr.txrs.bind(txr_map);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0); glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0); glVertex2f(+1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0); glVertex2f(+1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0); glVertex2f(-1.0,+1.0);
    glEnd();
    scr.txrs.unbind();
    // [info]
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    scr.text_init_pix(1.0);
    scr.text(tcpu);
    scr.text(tgpu);
    scr.text_exit();

    scr.exe();
    scr.rfs();

    tend(); tcpu=" CPU time: "+tstr(1);
    tim.tend();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::mouse(double x,double y,TShiftState sh)
    {
    x=divide(2.0*x,scr.xs)-1.0;
    y=1.0-divide(2.0*y,scr.ys);
    if (sh.Contains(ssLeft))
        {
        viewx+=x-mx;
        viewy+=y-my;
        view_compute();
        _redraw=true;
        }
    mx=x;
    my=y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
    {
    scr.init(this);
    txr_map=fbo.add(scr);
//  map_load_csv("map.csv");
//  map_save_bin("map.bin");
    map_load_bin("map.bin");
    map_bbox();
    view_compute();
    draw();
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    scr.exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    scr.resize();
    fbo.resize(scr);
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormMouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
    {
    if (Shift.Contains(ssShift))
        {
        if (WheelDelta>0) index++; else index--;
        if (index>=polygon.num) index=polygon.num-1;
        if (index<0) index=0;
        _redraw=true;
        }
    else{
        double p[3]={ mx,my,0.0 };
        view_compute();
        matrix_mul_vector(p,iview,p);
        if (WheelDelta>0) zoom*=dzoom; else zoom/=dzoom;
        view_compute();
        matrix_mul_vector(p,view,p);
        viewx-=p[0]-mx;
        viewy-=p[1]-my;
        view_compute();
        _redraw=true;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X,int Y) { mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
void __fastcall TMain::FormMouseUp(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) { mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
void __fastcall TMain::FormMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) { mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    tgpu=AnsiString().sprintf(" GPU time: [%8.3lf ms]",tim.time());
    if (_redraw) { draw(); _redraw=false; }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDblClick(TObject *Sender)
    {
    Width+=10; // ignore this had some bug in resize FBO texture and this was for debugging it
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

If you need help with the matrix and vector math routines see this:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

In the linked answers at the bottom you can find even the C++ implementations I use...

You can ignore the **VCL** stuff the app just have single Timer on it with interval `40 ms` to repaint if needed and fetch measuret GL time if ready...

The important stuff for you is just the `draw()` routine.

It works like this:

1. bind **FBO** to enable rendering to `texture`
2. clear it with `land color`
3. render polygons outline with `edge color`

   if you got holes render them with `watter color` and after filling render them again with `edge color`
4. render watter start points with `watter color`

   in the first frame you should have view un-zoomed so all land is surrounded with watter. So the first watter points are the border rectangle of texture.
5. unbind **FBO** and copy texture pixeldata to **CPU** side memory
6. grow fill all watter to `land color` pixels (stop on `edge color` or any other)

   You can use any fill like Flood fill, segmented line fill etc but beware stack overflow for recursive approach. I decided to use:

   - [grow fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412283/2521214)

   As it is iterative. It is not as fast (hence the big CPU times but big portion of the CPU time is due to sync while transfering texture between GPU/CPU) but can be speed-up significantly by subdividing image into "square" areas and propagate filling if needed.
7. create watter start points from this image

   so scan whole image (with some step do not need to scan all point) and if found watter add it as watter start point `watter` for next frame (in world coordinates). This works well until your view will not change too much from frame to frame so limit zoom change and pan step ...

   Here comes an gfx issue when new frame contains watter without any start points and not accessible to other watter. This need some thinking/testing but I think it should be solvable by some static predefined watter start points (few for each polygon) obtained from the first frame.
8. render **CPU** side image directly or pass it back to **GL** texture and render it.

Here preview:

[image: preview]

Comment: Inspiring, not fully understood though. I'll reconsider my design as you suggested.  There're other polygons and symbols except water and lands, will the flood fill way still work? And RT means?.

Comment: @ShaoboZi you can add the additional stuff after the backround is rendered ... Also is good idea to render only important stuff in respect to view position and zoom (no need to render 1m details when pixel is 100.0m big or markers outside view etc...) If you share some data I would like to try to code it in C++ as a proof of concept that it is doable in RT time ...

Comment: @ShaoboZi I was thinking  about converting your islands into set of horizontal slices/lines instead of triangulation. That would ease up this a lot And I think it would be also faster to compute.

Comment: I can share the data ,but its S57 format (ISO8211),  it's abit complicate to extract the actual polygon data.

Comment: Data file https://pan.baidu.com/s/1eS3Lp5o  code: eb44   .Btw, QGis is able to render that file pretty quickly , I do want to know how it's done by QGIS.

Comment: @ShaoboZi write a parser for that would take time ... cant you make just simple ASCII polygon export ?

Comment: I managed to extract one of the complex polygons with holes in it. https://pan.baidu.com/s/1mipwoA0

Comment: @ShaoboZi yep that works for me it has 181659 vertexes. When I will have the time will try to code the "triangulation" for this in the manner I was describing in the Answer.  Sadly the polygon is divided into sections so it is more polygons joined together which complicates things a bit But I think it would work even in this case. btw what is your accepted time for transformation of this ?

Comment: I got 2 choices. 1: Save the triangulation results,  render the triangles with OpenGL. Take the chart in the file I mentioned above as an example(it contains 700000+ vertexes), it takes me 3~4 min to get the triangulation done. I hope it could be done in less than 1 min.  2: Do not tessellate. Do flood or scan fill with OpenGL. It should be OK to render one chart within 100 ms.  Right now I'm trying some triangulation library.

Comment: BTW I was thinking if polygon simplification will boost the polygon fill process since the polygon simplification itself would cost some time.

Comment: @ShaoboZi heh had played with C++ and the data a bit and finally manage to make indices and segmented index sort (y ascending) point  table in `1.4 sec` but its crazy complicated binary search on segmented index tables (without it it took around minute). Now I want to fully index sort the segments and merge the polygons to single polygon outline. Then create the render/teselation stuff  but not today ...

Comment: Thanks so much and you can take your time.  Another question, is it common to do flood filling or scan filling with OpenGL when rendering polygons?

Comment: @ShaoboZi not at all such things are usually done on CPU side and raster graphics but in this case I will give it a shot (or approximate by horizontal lines/stripes) I estimate it would be much faster then triangulating ...

Comment: That's a piece of work! I need to delve into that. Thanks !

Comment: @ShaoboZi had a little time for this. I improved it a bit but still not done yet (I will edit only after all done but do not know when it will be possibly during next weekend) . I remember first frame watter start points permanently. All watter point are added to them but just for the next frame (as done till now) that got rid of the missing water during pan. Added polygon ID to binary map as all `ID` with `"ring"` inside means it is a hole. Now I am working on initializing watter start  points for them (almost done but have bug somewhere). Added polygon clipping and mouse selection

Comment: I'm trying to learn your example.  Busy with some other stuff these days :( . It should fit into my project. But I'm concerned about the filling efficiency.

Comment: @ShaoboZi yeah me too but it can be speeded up considerably by segmenting the screen into rectangular areas (I plan to implement it too as I need it for another project like most of the things for this :) )... Also I got an idea to ease up this by magnitude on GL side. I managed to create "fast" pseudo Hit test to tell if point is inside a polygon or not (for the start points) without probing FBO. It can be used to fast triangulate  inside grid so there would be much less pixels to fill

Comment: @ShaoboZi on full screen I got `~230-300 ms` for the watter fill (water is covering 75% of view) After implementing segmented grow fill the time is now `15-25ms` ... that is acceptable for my purposes... Oh they changed the look of SO again ... so confusing ...

Comment: @ShaoboZi added link to QA with code for my **FBO** class I used for this

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts that I have... can you split the tesselation into organized chunks, ... kind of like a grid? Then if things move you could intelligently only re-tesselate the parts that changed.

Comment: Another thought I have is how often are you calling the tesselation. can you run the tesselation on half of it every other frame for instance?

Comment: I call it just once for each chart