# how to retrieve z depth and color of a rendered pixel

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, depth-buffer, color-depth

I would like to retrieve the z height of each pixels of a rendered object in a scene.
I will need to retrieve the color rendered too.

What are the opengl technics to implement ?

Comment: use `glReadPixels` for example like this [depth buffer got by glReadPixels is always 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130948/2521214) and [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214)  you can obtain the whole screen both depth and color by it ...

Comment: Is it more efficient to use fragment shader ? if it permits it ?

Comment: Yes many times more efficient ... I moved the comments into answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **`glReadPixels` and CPU side code**

   use `glReadPixels` to obtain both RGB and Depth buffers. Here examples for both:

   - [depth buffer got by glReadPixels is always 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130948/2521214)
   - [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214)

   That will read the buffers into CPU accessible memory. This way is slow (due to sync) but should work on any platform.
2. **FBO render to texture and GPU shader**

   Faster method is to use [FBO and render to texture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43930271/2521214) and use that output in next rendering pass as input texture for computing your stuff inside shaders. This however will not run properly on **Intel** and might need additional tweaking of code between **nVidia** and **AMD**.

   If you have per pixel output use single `QUAD` covering your screen as the second rendering pass.

   If you got single output for the whole screen instead use single `POINT` render and compute all in the fragment shader (scann the whole texture inside) something like this:

   - [How to implement 2D raycasting light effect in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708022/2521214)

   The difference is that by usnig shaders and FBO you are not transferring data between **GPU/CPU** so its way faster.

   The content of the targeted textures can be still readed by **CPU** using texture related **GL** functions
3. **compute GPU shaders**

   There are also **compute shaders** out there but I did not use them yet so I am just guessing however with them it might be possible to do your stuff in single pass and also the form of the result and computation should not be as limiting.

My bet is that you are doing some post processing similar to [Deferred Shading](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Deferred-Shading) so googling such topic/tutorials might help.