# opengl es 2.0 android c++ glGetTexImage alternative

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

when testing on windows the code works as expected, but on android the `glGetTexImage` api doesn't exist, is there an other way of getting all the pixels from OpenGL without caching them before creating the texture?

this is the code:

```
void Texture::Bind(int unit)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);
}

GLubyte* Texture::GetPixels()
{
    Bind();

    int data_size = mWidth * mHeight * 4;

    GLubyte* pixels = new GLubyte[mWidth * mHeight * 4];

    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    return pixels;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) doesn't exist in OpenGL ES.
In OpenGL ES, you have to attach the texture to a framebuffer and read the color plane from the framebuffer by [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)

```cpp
Bind();
int data_size = mWidth * mHeight * 4;
GLubyte* pixels = new GLubyte[mWidth * mHeight * 4];

GLuint textureObj = ...; // the texture object - glGenTextures  

GLuint fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObj, 0);

glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
```