Using Compute Shader in OpenGL ES with kotlin
I want to Test out how the shaders and compute shaders work.
The compute shader should just color a pixel white and return it. and then the shader should use that color to paint the bottom of the screen.
the shader works fine, but when I tried to implement compute shader, it just does not work.
Take a look at this implementation of renderer.
these are the shaders
compute shader
#version 310 es
precision highp float;
precision highp image2D;

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in; // run only for one pixel
layout (rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform writeonly image2D outputImage;

void main() {
    ivec2 pixelCoords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    imageStore(outputImage, pixelCoords, vec4(1.0)); // just color it white and return
}

fragment shader
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else
precision mediump float;
#endif

// 'varying' values are passed from the vertex shader to the fragment shader
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform vec3 Accelerometer;// I removed the part of code that puts this data for simplicity
uniform sampler2D ColorSet;// single pixel texture returned from compute shader

void main() {
    if (gl_FragCoord.y > 250.0) {
        float x = Accelerometer[0] / 20.0;
        float y = Accelerometer[1] / 20.0;
        float z = Accelerometer[2] / 20.0;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, z + 0.5, 1.0);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(ColorSet, vec2(1.0));
    }
}

I think this is correct but please harass me if I am wrong, the problem should be the implementation of the renderer
Renderer
class MyGLRenderer(
) : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private var computeShaderProgram = 0
    private var program = 0

    private val uniformLocations: MutableList<MutableMap<String, Int?>> = mutableListOf()
    private val uniformValues: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()

    private var textures = IntArray(1)// only one texture
    private var resolution = floatArrayOf(0f,0f)

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(unused: GL10?, config: EGLConfig?) {

        createTextures()
        vertexShader = createVertexShader()
        computeProgram = createComputeProgram()
        renderProgram = createRenderProgram()
    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10?) {
        GLES31.glClear(GLES31.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GLES31.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        dispatchComputeShader()
        readAndLogPixelFromTexture(0, Pair(0,0))
        drawTexture()
    }
}

    private fun createTextures() {
        GLES31.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0)
        GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0])

// Set texture parameters
        GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES31.GL_LINEAR)
        GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES31.GL_LINEAR)
        GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES31.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES31.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

// Allocate storage for the texture with the correct format and type
        GLES31.glTexImage2D(
            GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GLES31.GL_RGBA8,       // Use RGBA32F for floating-point support
            1,                       // Texture width
            1,                       // Texture height
            0,
            GLES31.GL_RGBA,
            GLES31.GL_FLOAT,         // Ensure FLOAT format for the shader compatibility
            null                     // No initial data; just allocate storage
        )
// Unbind the texture
        GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    }

private fun createVertexShader(): Int {
        return compileShader(GLES31.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vertexCode)
    }

private fun createComputeProgram(): Int {
        return GLES31.glCreateShader(GLES31.GL_COMPUTE_SHADER).also { shader ->
            GLES31.glShaderSource(shader,computeCode)
            GLES31.glCompileShader(shader)

            val compileStatus = IntArray(1)
            GLES31.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES31.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0)

            if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
                val infoLog = GLES31.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)
                GLES31.glDeleteShader(shader)
                throw RuntimeException("Compute Shader compilation failed: $infoLog")
            }
        }
    }
private fun createRenderProgram(): Int {

        val fragmentShader = compileShader(GLES31.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,rendererCode)
        return GLES31.glCreateProgram().also {
            GLES31.glAttachShader(it, vertexShader)
            GLES31.glAttachShader(it, fragmentShader)
            GLES31.glLinkProgram(it)

            // Check for linking errors
            val linkStatus = IntArray(1)
            GLES31.glGetProgramiv(it, GLES31.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0)
            if (linkStatus[0] == 0) {
                GLES31.glDeleteProgram(it)
                Timber.tag("renderer").d("not linked successfully")
                throw RuntimeException("Could not link program: ${GLES31.glGetProgramInfoLog(it)}")
            }
            else{
                Timber.tag("renderer").d("linked successfully")
            }
        }
    }
private fun compileShader(type: Int, shaderCode: String): Int {
        return GLES31.glCreateShader(type).also { shader ->
            GLES31.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode)
            GLES31.glCompileShader(shader)

            // Check for compilation errors
            val compiled = IntArray(1)
            GLES31.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES31.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0)
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Timber.e("Shader compilation failed: %s", GLES31.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader))
                GLES31.glDeleteShader(shader)
            }
        }
    }

fun dispatchComputeShader() {
        GLES31.glUseProgram(computeProgram)
        GLES31.glBindImageTexture(0, textures[0], 0, false, 0, GLES31.GL_WRITE_ONLY, GLES31.GL_RGBA32F)

        // Assuming resolution width and height are divisible by 16 or 1 (for testing)
        GLES31.glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1)
        GLES31.glMemoryBarrier(GLES31.GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT)
    }
fun readAndLogPixelFromTexture(texture: Int, pixel:Pair<Int, Int>) {
        val pixelData = FloatArray(4)
        GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[texture])
        GLES31.glReadPixels(pixel.first, pixel.second, 1, 1, GLES31.GL_RGBA, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, java.nio.FloatBuffer.wrap(pixelData))

        // Log the color value to verify it
        val r = pixelData[0]
        val g = pixelData[1]
        val b = pixelData[2]
        val a = pixelData[3]
        Timber.d("SET-COLOR: R: $r, G: $g, B: $b, A: $a")
    }
private fun drawTexture() {
        GLES31.glUseProgram(renderProgram)

        val positionHandle = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(renderProgram, "aPosition")
        GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle)

        val textureCoordHandle = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(renderProgram, "aTexCoord")
        GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle)

        val textureHandle = GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(renderProgram, "ColorSet")
        GLES31.glActiveTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE0)
        GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0])
        GLES31.glUniform1i(textureHandle, 0)

        // Example vertices and texture coordinates
        val vertices = floatArrayOf(
            -1.0f, 1.0f,  // top left
            -1.0f, -1.0f, // bottom left
            1.0f, -1.0f,  // bottom right
            1.0f, 1.0f    // top right
        )

        val textureCoords = floatArrayOf(
            0.0f, 0.0f,   // top left
            0.0f, 1.0f,   // bottom left
            1.0f, 1.0f,   // bottom right
            1.0f, 0.0f    // top right
        )

        val vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.size * 4).run {
            order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            asFloatBuffer().apply {
                put(vertices)
                position(0)
            }
        }

        val textureCoordBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.size * 4).run {
            order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            asFloatBuffer().apply {
                put(textureCoords)
                position(0)
            }
        }

        GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(
            positionHandle, 2,
            GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, vertexBuffer
        )

        GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(
            textureCoordHandle, 2,
            GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, textureCoordBuffer
        )

        GLES31.glDrawArrays(GLES31.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4)

        GLES31.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle)
        GLES31.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle)
    }

The bottom of the screen should be white with this setup but it is stuck at black.
I tried logging the color of the only pixel of the texture and it also turned out to be RGBA(0,0,0,0)
Can any one help me out.

Possibly, you are using the wrong memory barrier. Did you try GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT?

Also, try to use the GL_RGBA8 texture format (instead of GL_RGBA32F) and layout (rgba32f, binding = 0) in the shader.

First of all, you must instead of GLES31.glTexImage2D create immutable texture to be able a compute shader to write on it:
    GLES31.glTexStorage2D(
        GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        1,                       // 1 level
        GLES31.GL_RGBA32F,
        1,                       // Texture width
        1,                       // Texture height
    )

Secondly, referring to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993894/7167920
ES version of OpenGL does not support using texture image data directly, you should use FrameBuffer.
Initialize it when you init:
frameBuffers = IntArray(1)
GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBuffers, 0)

And here the working code of readAndLogPixelFromTexture():
checkGLError { GLES31.glBindFramebuffer(GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffers[0]) }
checkGLError {
        GLES31.glFramebufferTexture2D(
            GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
            GLES31.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            textures[texture],
            0
        )
    }
if (GLES31.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   throw RuntimeException("Framebuffer is not complete")
}
val pixelData = FloatArray(4)
GLES31.glReadPixels(pixel.first, pixel.second, 1, 1, GLES31.GL_RGBA, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, FloatBuffer.wrap(pixelData))
checkGLError { GLES31.glBindFramebuffer(GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0) }

// Log the color value to verify it
val r = pixelData[0]
val g = pixelData[1]
val b = pixelData[2]
val a = pixelData[3]
Log.d(TAG, "Compute shader result: R: $r, G: $g, B: $b, A: $a")

