# c# detect points of polygon in black/white image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I have to detect all the points of a white polygon on a black background in c#.  Here is an image of several examples.  I wouldn't think it is too difficult, but I am unable to detect this properly with all the variations.  My code is too much to post here, but basically I went through each side and look for when it changes from black and white.  Should I use Open CV?  I was hoping for a simple algorithm I could implement in C#.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: it is unclear what you want ... all points of polygon is ROI mask and you already got that so I am assuming you need the Vertexes (edge points) ... in that case yes you first find contours (all white pixels next to any black pixel)  and then apply either connected components analysis or hough transform to detect lines .... after that the vertexes are just intersections of all lines ... or extremes with changing slope angle ....

Comment: A simple algorithm would be floodfill. You can easily implement it yourself. For example like [this link](https://www.google.de/amp/s/simpledevcode.wordpress.com/2015/12/29/flood-fill-algorithm-using-c-net/amp/). After you get all your connected points you search for your upper-left, upper-right... corner points.

Comment: thanks for replies, yes I need to get the points. I will check out hough transformation or connected components analysis.  I don't think simple algorithm to detect corner points will work for example the middle right image would have 7 points.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would do this:

1. **pre process image**

   so remove noise in color if present (like **JPG** distortion etc) and binarize image.
2. **select circumference pixels**

   simply loop through all pixels and set each white pixel that has at least one black neighbor to distinct color that will represent your circumference **ROI** mask or add the pixel position to some list of points instead.
3. **apply connected components analysis**

   so you need to find out the order of the points (how are connected together). The easiest way to do this is use flood filing of the **ROI** from first found pixel until all **ROI** is filled and remember the order of filled points (similar to **A***). There should be 2 distinct paths at some point and both should join at last. So identify these 2 points and construct the circumference point order (by reversing one half and handling the shared part if present).

   [image: connected components]
4. **find vertexes**

   if you compute the angle change between all consequent pixels then on straight lines the angle change should be near zero and near vertexes much bigger. So threshold that and you got your vertexes. To make this robust you need to compute slope angle from a bit more distant pixels then the closest pixels. Also thresholding this angle change against sliding average often provides more stable results.

   [image: edge detect]

   So find out how far the pixels should be to compute angle so you got not too big noise and vertexes has still big peaks and also find out the threshold value that is safe above any noise.

   This can be done also by **hough transform** and or **find contours** functions that are present in many **CV** libs. Another option is also **regress/fit** the lines in the point list directly and compute intersections which can provide sub pixel precision.

**For more info see related QAs:**

- [Backtracking in A star](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28317199/2521214)
- [Finding holes in 2d point sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884021/2521214)
- [growth fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412283/2521214)